# Error installing node-sass on io.js 1.4.1 on Yosemite

Tags: node.js, nvm, broccolijs, io.js, node-sass

I have a fresh install of io.js 1.4.1 on Yosemite via NVM. When I try to install node-sass, I get this error:

```
$ npm install node-sass
/
> node-sass@2.0.1 install /Users/Chris/code/<projectname>/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Can not download file from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sass/node-sass-binaries/v2.0.1/darwin-x64-iojs-1.4/binding.node

> node-sass@2.0.1 postinstall /Users/Chris/code/<projectname>/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

module.js:322
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/Chris/code/<projectname>/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/pangyp/bin/node-gyp'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:320:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:262:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:485:10)
    at startup (node.js:112:16)
    at node.js:863:3
Build failed
node-sass@2.0.1 node_modules/node-sass
├── get-stdin@4.0.1
├── object-assign@2.0.0
├── replace-ext@0.0.1
├── nan@1.6.2
├── semver@4.3.1
├── shelljs@0.3.0
├── cross-spawn@0.2.6 (lru-cache@2.5.0)
├── mkdirp@0.5.0 (minimist@0.0.8)
├── chalk@0.5.1 (ansi-styles@1.1.0, escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@0.2.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0, has-ansi@0.1.0)
├── meow@3.1.0 (minimist@1.1.0, camelcase-keys@1.0.0, indent-string@1.2.1)
├── npmconf@2.1.1 (uid-number@0.0.5, inherits@2.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, ini@1.3.3, once@1.3.1, config-chain@1.1.8, nopt@3.0.1)
├── sass-graph@1.0.3 (commander@2.6.0, lodash@2.4.1)
├── gaze@0.5.1 (globule@0.1.0)
├── mocha@2.1.0 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.2, diff@1.0.8, growl@1.8.1, commander@2.3.0, debug@2.0.0, glob@3.2.3, jade@0.26.3)
└── request@2.53.0 (caseless@0.9.0, json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, aws-sign2@0.5.0, stringstream@0.0.4, oauth-sign@0.6.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, isstream@0.1.1, node-uuid@1.4.2, qs@2.3.3, combined-stream@0.0.7, form-data@0.2.0, mime-types@2.0.9, http-signature@0.10.1, tough-cookie@0.12.1, bl@0.9.4, hawk@2.3.1)
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is this a bug? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is related to this issue:

https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/699

Comment: yeah that was pretty much it. I basically wiped out the local directory and grabbed an older version of node and installed it. That made it work

Answer (score 1):

Moving pangyp from dev to default dependency in package.json is the fix for this problem. This is merged in master and should be in the next release, see:

https://github.com/sass/node-sass/pull/714